# How to place a content div block between the left and right column if this block is higher?

Tags: html, css

I need to place content between the left and right columns, provided that the content  block is higher than the left and right column  blocks. I tried to use float: right; in the styles for the content, it only aligns the example in the figure.

[image]

How to center the content  block between columns?
My code is:

```css
#left {
    width:220px;
    height:200px;
    background:yellow;
    float:right;
}

#content {
    float:right;
}

#right {
    width:220px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    background:grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">Content</div>
    <div id="left">left col</div>
    <div id="right">right col</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What meant by _provided that the content block is higher than the left and right column blocks._

Answer (score 1):

Just use `flex` for this.  Reorder the `div`s to put the `#content` in the middle and tell the `#content` element to fill the remaining space:

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#left {
  width:220px;
  height:200px;
  background:yellow;
}
#content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
#right {
  width:220px;
  height:200px;
  background:grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" > 
<head><title>Example</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="left">left col</div>
    <div id="content">Content</div>
    <div id="right">right col</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you **absolutely must** have the `content` element first then use `order` to sort the column order out:

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#left {
  width:220px;
  height:200px;
  background:yellow;
  order: 1;
}
#content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  order: 2;
}
#right {
  width:220px;
  height:200px;
  background:grey;
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" > 
<head><title>Example</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">Content</div>
    <div id="left">left col</div>
    <div id="right">right col</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case i prefer to use flex

```css
.flex-row-container {
    background: #aaa;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.flex-row-container > .flex-row-item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex: 1 1 30%;
    height: 100px;
}

.flex-row-item {
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  border: 1px solid #f76707;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row-container">
  <div class="flex-row-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-row-item">2</div>
  <div class="flex-row-item">3</div>
  <div class="flex-row-item">4</div>
  <div class="flex-row-item">5</div>
  <div class="flex-row-item">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the structure

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" > 
<head><title>Example</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="left">left col</div>
    <div id="content">Content</div>
    <div id="right">right col</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that ***without* changing the HTML**.

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  width: 220px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  order: 1;
}

#content {
  order: 2;
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 1;
}

#right {
  width: 220px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="content">Content</div>
  <div id="left">left col</div>
  <div id="right">right col</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to restructure your HTML part. Write the **content** div between the **left** and **right** divs. To the left div(i.e for #left), make your CSS **float: left**, and to the right div (i.e for #right) write **float: right**.

Also, since there is a content in middle, you can give #content a float:left property.

There are many ways how you can align these divs adjacent for example: flexbox, you can also use bootstrap row and column classes to align them properly.

**But it seems that you are a beginner and that's why I am providing the minimal description solution to help you understand better**

**Please check my code snippet result down.**

```css
#left {
    width:220px;
    height:200px;
    background:yellow;
    float:left;
}

#content{
float:left;
}

#right {
    width:220px;
    height:200px;
    float:right;
    background:grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    
    <div id="left">left col</div>
    <div id="content">Content</div>
    <div id="right">right col</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Here is another option.

Comment: ```<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" > 
<head><title>Example</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">Content</div>
    <div id="left">left col</div>
    <div id="right">right col</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ```
#left {
    width:220px;
    height:200px;
    background:yellow;
    float:right;
}

#content {
   position:absolute;
   margin-left:220px;
   
}

#right {
    width:220px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    background:grey;
}
```

Comment: @Lex34 You are welcome! and yes, you could use this as well.